# How to change page languages automatically for all pages on Typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, language-translation

We have changed the primary language for our site https://staging.venicexplorer.net from English to Italian. But the problem is it is showing English text when we selected Italian and vice versa. We are now altering the languages of the content. But this is a very time consuming job. Can anyone please tell me whether there is any shortcut method?

Thanks
Prasun

Comment: Could you add what you changed already? Is your new "primary" language now the default/standard language in the backend? What is in the database table sys_languages (especially interesting: which uid does English have now?) and how is the language setup in your Site Config?

Comment: Our default /standard language in the backend is English. On frontend there were two languages. One is English and another is Italian. English was the default language. But we have decided the default frontend language should be Italian. So we are now altering the language content one by one.
uid for English is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints for updating the language of content and pages in the database:

**Content**

The language of a content element (table `tt_content`) is in the field `sys_language_uid`. Default language is always 0, "all languages" is -1.

Each translated record (`sys_language_uid NOT IN (0,1)`) can (aka "connected mode") have a link to its default language counterpart. This is set in the field `l10n_parent`.

**Pages**

First of all for TYPO3v9 this depends on the feature toggle [unifiedPageTranslationHandling](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.2/Feature-83711-FeatureFlagUnifiedPageTranslationHandling.html). I will assume that your instance is already fully migrated to not use `pages_language_overlay` any more.

The same rules as for `tt_content` apply: `sys_language_uid` is the language, `l10n_parent` the default language record.

**Other records**

The same applies to all other translated records in TYPO3 or its extensions.

Technically, these fields are defined for each table in [TCA](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Ctrl/Index.html) in `[ctrl][languageField]` and `[ctrl][transOrigPointerField]` but `sys_language_uid` and `l10n_parent` are used mostly.

**Notice**

This is not an exhaustive list. There are fields that are only set in the default language (e.g. access restrictions). Make a backup first! But that should cover most bases.

Comment: Hi Jonas,

Thank you for the reply. That is much helpful!

Regards
Prasun